# await this.$nextTick() re executes the method in which it is used

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
async mounted() {
        debugger;
        // console.log(this.numberFormat);
        this.accountsInfo = await this.accounts;
        this.paginatedRows = this.accountsInfo.data.rows;
        // this.paginatedRows.forEach((row) => {
        //     if (row.excludeInAggregate) {
        //         // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        //         row.name += " (Excluded from Client Aggregate)";
        //     }
        // });
        this.excludedAccountsDict = this.accountsInfo.data.rows.filter((x) => x.excludeInAggregate).map((x) => x.id);
        this.render = true;
        await this.disableRows();
    },
```

```
 async disableRows() {
            debugger;
            console.log("1", this.excludedAccountsDict);
            await this.$nextTick();
            console.log("2", this.excludedAccountsDict);
            this.excludedAccountsDict.forEach((element) => {
                const row = document.getElementById(element);
                if (row) {
                    row.children[1].innerHTML += "<div>(Excluded from Client Aggregate)</div>";
                    const checkbox = row.getElementsByClassName("mds-checkbox__input_app")[0];
                    if (checkbox) {
                        checkbox.disabled = true;
                    }
                    row.classList.add("disable-rows");
                }
            });
        },
```

debugger in disableRows methods get triggered twice, also the code after nextTick executes twice.

Expectation: at nextTick, everything should be halted until DOM updates

I made sure mounted ran only once.

Comment: You could comment the nextTick so you know it's its fault and not something else's. Does it still run twice after commenting?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, second call was coming from watcher. Thanks :)